# Django REST Framework: I want to resolve n+1 in SerializerMethodField

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a queryset that returns Boolean from a queryset prefetched with a reverse reference by `SerializerMethodField`, as shown in the code below.
I'm creating one that determines if there is an object for the current user and returns Boolean.
However, when I use the prefetched queryset to filter by the current user as shown below, a new queryset is issued instead of the prefetched queryset, and the n+1 problem occurs.

In the following code, how can we save the queryset and return
Booelan?

```py
# serializers.py

class VideoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    is_viewed = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    is_favorited = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    is_wl = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Video
        fields = (
            "pk",
            "is_viewed",
            "is_favorited",
            "is_wl",
        )

    @staticmethod
    def setup_eager_loading(queryset):
        queryset.prefetch_related('history_set', 'favorite_set')

    def get_is_viewed(self, obj):
        user = self.context["request"].user
        if user.is_authenticated:
            try:
                obj.history_set.get(user=user) # <- here
                return True
            except History.DoesNotExist:
                pass
        return False

    def get_is_favorited(self, obj):
        user = self.context["request"].user
        if user.is_authenticated:
            try:
                obj.favorite_set.get(user=user) # <- here
                return True
            except Favorite.DoesNotExist:
                pass
        return False

    def get_is_wl(self, obj):
        user = self.context["request"].user
        if user.is_authenticated:
            try:
                Track.objects.get(playlist__user=user, playlist__is_wl=True, video=obj)
                return True
            except Track.DoesNotExist:
                pass
        return False
```

[A large number of query sets were issued.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WViwA.png)

```py
#models.py

class Video(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField("title", max_length=300)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class History(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    video = models.ForeignKey(Video, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user}, {self.video.title}"

class Favorite(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    video = models.ForeignKey(Video, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user}, {self.video.title}"
```

Comment: please add your models.py

Comment: I've just added models.py.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Exists](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries) subquery.

```py
Video.objects.annotate(is_favorite=Exists(Favorite.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, video=OuterRef("id"))))
```

After that you can access `is_favorite` attribute.

```py
class VideoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    is_viewed = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    is_favorited = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    is_wl = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Video
        fields = (
            "pk",
            "is_viewed",
            "is_favorited",
            "is_wl",
        )

    @staticmethod
    def setup_eager_loading(queryset):
        queryset.prefetch_related('history_set', 'favorite_set')

    def get_is_viewed(self, obj):
        user = self.context["request"].user
        if user.is_authenticated:
            try:
                obj.history_set.get(user=user) # <- here
                return True
            except History.DoesNotExist:
                pass
        return False

    def get_is_favorited(self, obj):
        return obj.is_favorite

    def get_is_wl(self, obj):
        user = self.context["request"].user
        if user.is_authenticated:
            try:
                Track.objects.get(playlist__user=user, playlist__is_wl=True, video=obj)
                return True
            except Track.DoesNotExist:
                pass
        return False
```

You can add annotations for other fields (is_views, is_wl)

Comment: For nested serializers, how can they be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

Another query being made with prefetch_related method call is intended. You can find it in django documentation.

[image]

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/

I think using subquery and Exists query expression is better option, as 'Utkucan Bıyıklı' suggested.

Answer (score 0):

By reverse reference, i understand you are referring a foreignkey field, in that case you need to use `select_related`, `prefetch_related` is used for many-many fields.
Based on it you can use any of the below code. make sure to **return** the queryset.

```
 @staticmethod
 def setup_eager_loading(queryset):
     #prefetch_related for 'to-many' relationships
     queryset.prefetch_related('history_set', 'favorite_set')
     return quesyset


 @staticmethod
 def setup_eager_loading(queryset):
     #select_related for 'foreign key' relationships 
     queryset = queryset.select_related('history_set', 'favorite_set')
     return queryset
```